# malloc and realloc array giving unexpected output

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

When input is '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11' Expected output should be the same as input. Yet the output is '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -1850774484' . Only happens when there are more than 10 integers being inputted. Where did I go wrong with my realloc line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INITIAL_SIZE 10

int
main(int argc, char **argv){
    int i = 0, num, size = 0, n = INITIAL_SIZE;
    int *A;

    A = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    if(A == NULL){
        printf("OUT OF MEMORY\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(scanf("%d",&num) == 1 && getchar()!='\n'){
        A[i] = num;
        i++;
        size++;
        if (size >= n){
            n = n * 2;
            A = realloc(A,n * sizeof(int));
        }
    }

    printf("Int Array: ");
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the `realloc`. You are printing an extra uninitialized index in the last loop. Fix it by changing

```
for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

---

The only problem with the `realloc` is that you don't check if it was successful just like you did for the `malloc`. Another problem is that you don't free the allocated memory.

Comment: that only prints 1 to 10 and leaves out 11 for some reason

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Do you input a newline character at the end?

Comment: yep my input is '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11\n' and output gives '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10' . it seems if i remove the 'getchar()...' part and end by using control-D instead gives me the correct output though

Comment: There is an issue with the new-line reading, but there's still an issue with `malloc`, too: For example, when `i` is 10, you assign ´A[10]`, which is one element after the permissible range. Blue Moon is right, although the re-allocation should go before bhoth assignment and size/counter update.

Comment: I proposed `while(scanf("%d",&num) == 1){
  A[i] = num;
  if(getchar()=='\n')break;`

Comment: @Qbb , Use BLUEPIXY's solution instead or add `A[i]=num; size++; i++;` after the `while` loop.

Comment: @CoolGuy is this case , N/C original.(`i <= size`) but Meaning does not fit :-)

Comment: @MOehm Read `i` as next index and `size` as current size! When we pass `A[i] = num;` with `i == 9` both `i` and `size` are incremented to `10` and the `realloc` is triggered because it uses `size >= n` (*or equal to*). So I think the loop is fine - except it could perform an unnecessarily reallocation which is why we would normally reallocate before assignment. However this code is valid.

Comment: @DanAllen: Yes, you're right. `i` is accessed before it is incremented. I got that wrong, because I usually enlarge the space just before I need it, not after it. Sorry for that.

Comment: just tried BLUEPIXY's solution adding `if (getchar()=='\n')break;` right after A[i] = num; and it gave a really weird output:1 3 5 7 9 0 . skipping second number for some reason.

Comment: @Qbb , I'm getting too confused. [Here](http://rextester.com/JGXE96231) is the solution which uses BLUEPIXY's method. Note that I've not freed or checked the return value of `realloc` in the code.

Comment: @CoolGuy ok that works it seems i placed the if(getchar.. too early.sorry to bother you .  thanks for your help!!!